# Combining array lists containing different objects in Java

Tags: java, object, arraylist

im working on a small game in Java. I have an abstract class **SuperHero**, and the classes WaterHero and LandHero that extends from **Superhero**. How do I combine the two objects **allHeroes** and **allHeroes2** in an array list? I don't want to loop though multiple array list when writing methods later.

```
ArrayList<WaterHero> allHeroes = new ArrayList<>();  
ArrayList<LandHero> allHeroes2 = new ArrayList<>();

allHeroes.add(new WaterHero("SharkHero", 100, 27, 13));  
allHeroes.add(new WaterHero("Fishy", 100, 30, 22));  
allHeroes2.add(new LandHero("Iron Man", 120, 25, 16));  
allHeroes2.add(new LandHero("LandBoy", 120, 25, 16));
```

I tried using `ArrayList<Object> Heroes= new ArrayList<>();` but dont really understand how this works, and how to reach methods from **SuperHero**. For example i could not reach getName() in superclass **SuperHero**

Comment: `List<> heroes = new ArrayList<Superhero>();`

Answer (score 0):

> `ArrayList<Object> Heroes= new ArrayList<>()`

We write `variablesLikeThis` and `TypesLikeThis`. So, `heroes`, not `Heroes`.

`ArrayList<Object>` means it can contain objects. And a lot of things are 'objects'. You would be allowed to stick an `Integer` object in there. It has no `getName()` method, thus, `heroes.get(0).getName()` won't compile. Yes, yes, you didn't put an integer in there, but the compiler doesn't know that. There is no guarantee. Java doesn't let you write code that *potentially* makes no sense, even if *currently* it always will. That's what compile-time type-checking means.

Instead you want `List<SuperHero>`: That is a list where every element is some sort of superhero. Could be a WaterHero instance, or a LandHero instance, as long as it's an instance of X such that X is either `SuperHero` or some type that `extends SuperHero` (or extends something that extends SuperHero - just needs to be anywhere in the type hierarchy).

Now that you've told java that, whatever might be in the list, it's all definitely superheroes, you can call methods on anything from the list that java knows, **for sure**, it'll have. All methods that `class SuperHero` has, for example - given that you said everything in the list is at least that, all of those methods are fine.